# How to use CSS with dynamically inserted elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, element, dynamic

How can I insert an element (`<ui>`) dynamically with some formatting inside an already existing element?

E.g.:

```
$("#contentDiv").append('<ui id="contentUi">');
$("#contentUi").css({ "text-align": "center", "list-style-type": "none"});
$("#contentDiv").css({ "text-decoration": "none","font-size":" 1.30em","font-weight": 
          "bold"});
```

Here `#contentDiv` is the id of an element `<div id="contentDiv">`, and I'm appending a new element `<ui>` to it.

Line 3 is working perfectly fine but line 2 has no effect on screen.

Comment: Why don't you paste it all in line 3? Why is there a #ContentUI in the second line and what do you append? You need to explain your question some more.

Comment: I agree with @Tim - more information needed, give relevant (pared-down) html, and i suggest you change title (no stylesheet involved in question) and tag jquery and javascript

Comment: What is #contentUi here? And what is that element("") anyway? Empty string or real element you mean? Is #contentUi the element you're trying to insert?

Comment: Everything working fine here http://jsfiddle.net/niklasvh/uw7PV/

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to define the css with jQuery here I think. Just have a class predefined in your stylesheet, mush simpler that way.

For an example.

```
$("#contentDiv").append('<ui class="predefined-class">');
$("#contentDiv").addClass('another-predefined-class');
```

And in your CSS you would have

```
.predefined-class {
     text-align: center; 
     list-style-type: none;
}

.another-predefined-class {
     text-decoration:none;
     font-size: 1.30em;
     font-weight: bold;
}
```

I hope this is what you were after.

Also I do not know how good is you appending an empty `ul`, since it is purposeless without the `li`s

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to add list-styles to a non-existent element `<ui>`

Change this line

`$("#contentDiv").append('<ui id="contentUi">');`

to

`$("#contentDiv").append('<ul id="contentUi">');`

Note: `ui` to `ul`

http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/NKZS3/